# Choosing a Web Framework for a Web Mobile App

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mobile-website, web-frameworks

I want to experiment a bit with web applications (and especially mobile web application). I am currently investigating on the framework to use on the server side, as I would like to develop a clean code following the MVC model.

I am thinking of using the Play Framework, in combination with jQuery, and the FormFactor JS library for the Javascript client side.

As it is my first experience of mobile web app development, I am very welcome to any suggestions you might have, regarding the technologies to use and the process to follow to  get started.

Thank you very much.

Additional Question: Do you know which web framework used the Financial Times for their great iPad web application? For the client side, it seems they used jQuery with a few libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Play framework and jQuery mobile before and would definitely recommend them. jQuery mobile is absolutely amazing, easy to use and insanely fast to develop with. I have since moved onto asp.net MVC but if your set on using java (And ofcourse you have the added bonus of easy deployment) Play is extremely good.

Comment: My concern is mostly about the scalability of Play Framework. There is not so many examples of web applications running on this framework out there, except from the authors of Play themselves.

Comment: Yeah its a very good point, play does not seem to be very widly used. I personally don't like java all that much but the project I worked on was just a rather small website. Play is nice but I do much prefer asp.net MVC probably due to enjoying c# more and having experience with entity framework. There are some good PHP MVC projects around, if you know PHP ofcourse.

Comment: I have had a little experience using http://kohanaframework.org/ and from what I've seen it seems very good. Worth having a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). It's very easy to set up, learn, and use, and has great [jQuery integration](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/10), including a [jQuery Mobile plugin](http://web2py.com/plugins/plugin_jqmobile/about). The [online book](http://web2py.com/book) should get you going, and if you need any help, there's a very active [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&pli=1#!forum/web2py).